# How to analyse this diode circuit

Tags: diodes, analog

[image]

what will be the voltage at Vx if D1 and D2 are practical diodes

This is not a problem from some text book. This circuit came in my mind while i was studying differential amplifiers.

Comment: found that both the diodes will be forward biased. but have no idea about which diode model to use

Comment: Are we assuming a .7V drop cross the diodes or are these like the .2V drop kinds?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both diodes have the same forward voltage then only D2 will be forward biased and conducting most of the current. D1 will just have leakage current from .2 volts below its forward bias. Vx = 0.2V - Vforward, assuming no leakage in D1.  Schematic below can be used to simulate the dc levels.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF6Wkh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

did a LTSPice simulation for circuit below

D1 at 9mA and D2 at 127uA

[image]